# What to do when you can't print your boarding pass?

Tags: tickets, regulations, paperwork, yvr, air-canada

I just use web checkin for my flight tomorrow. After that I should have printed my boarding pass. However, I realised that this is not possible. So what can I do now? I have already checked in, but no boarding pass. Is there any way to print that again at the airport? Or is it enough if I have my confirmation number? Or the boarding pass as a PDF?

Comment: Your question is a general question, but your tags suggest it's related to some Canadian airport. This is causing confusion with those trying to answer your question. It would make sense to edit your question to either make it clearly generic, or clearly specific.

Comment: It is about this specific airline and airport. I thought thats what tags are for. I will edit my question when Im back at my laptop.

Comment: I understand your line of thought. Still, I would think that tags somehow 'condense' the scope of the post, not expand it. :)

Comment: @RoflcoptrException Is it possible to state the name of the airline & airport within the context of your question ?

Comment: I **never, ever** print crap when the airline asks me to do so on their web site. When I get to the airport I just state **I do not have a printer, here's the info** and I give them my phone or whatever with the info shown on it. I've never had a problem (what could they do?)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Many of the major airlines do have self-service checkin machines at the airport. I know [KLM](http://www.klm.com/travel/nl_en/prepare_for_travel/checkin_options/airport_checkin/index.htm), allows printing forgotten or failed prints.

If your airlines does not have these self service machines, and you are not yet at the airport, try going to a print or copyshop. Most airports these days have these shops, but sometimes they can have quite some waiting queues, which will be adding stress to your journey.

Depending on the airline you are traveling, you could choose to use a [mobile device](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2907/can-you-use-a-kindle-as-a-boarding-pass) as an alternative boarding card. This only works if your boarding pass has a bar code they use to scan prior to boarding. What you need to do is make a pdf of your boarding pass and store it on your device. I always do this these days and this already  saved me once.

A final option is to just approach the check in desk and ask a reprint. This is the least favorable solution, since the whole idea behind online check in is to minimize contact time at a manned checkin desk. Some airlines are then reluctant to help you in these request, some airlines (Ryanair comes to mind) have a hefty fee if you ask for a reprint. In the case of Ryanair this is 40 euros or even higher.

Comment: not relevant here, but if you forget to print your boarding pass with RyanAir, they charge you to print it at the airport!

Comment: Not all airlines’ self-service machines will allow you to reprint a boarding pass if you’ve already checked in online, so you might have to join the ordinary check-in queue. (I encountered this problem with Germanwings at CGN last year.)

Comment: [And Ryanair isn't sympathetic to these cases either.](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/travelnews/9522191/Ryanair-boss-slams-idiot-who-forgot-boarding-pass.html)

Comment: Note that the scanner at the gate may or may not be able to recognize the barcode. However, if this happens, the personnel at the gate might be able to print a boarding pass for you.

Comment: Making a PDF of the boarding pass is probably the best solution among the ones suggested. Most boarding passes in today's date come along with a barcode. So that should be a proper alternative to it. My question though, is that does the same apply in case I had acquired a hard copy of the boarding pass from the counter and had lost/misplaced it (say while waiting at the airport lobby)?

Comment: What! 40 Euros for a paper?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Yes. EU citizen don't have to print the boarding pass, but passengers with other nationalities do. Failing to check-in till 2 hour before departure time results in a fine of 45 euros. For the case of having checked-in already but forget to print the boarding pass, the fine is 15 eur.

Comment: Cannot agree more with "the scanner at the gate may or may not recognise the barcode". If only I know that before, it would be a lot less of trouble.

Answer (score 18):

I fly Air Canada as my primary airline. It is worth checking in online even if you don't have a printer available. There are no negative consequences compared to not checking in at all. You can line up to see someone and hand off your baggage, and they'll "reprint" your boarding pass, or you can use the kiosks (I have never seen a lineup for AC kiosks, unlike United for example) and go through the checkin process again. You will retain your original checkin time should that become relevant for things like processing upgrades or deciding who loses their seat on an equipment change. (See my answer to ["Benefits of checking in online when checking bags"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/2323/46).)

Comment: I ran into a problem with this approach the other day departing St Louis: no self-service kiosks, and no agent working at the Air Canada counter! I had to go ask somebody from the United counter to go to the Air Canada counter and print one off for me. From now on, I'll always preprint if I'm unsure!

Comment: The same thing would have happened if you hadn't checked in, though, right? The question was "if you can't print it, is there even any point?" and I believe that there is.

Comment: I arrived at the airport within 60 minutes of flight time, so in my case it did make a difference. Which of course means you're right that checking in online can never harm, only help!

Answer (score 7):

You can reprint it at the airport, no problem. If no self-service station is available, the regular check-in desk personnel will reprint it for you.

Some airlines in some locations allow using "mobile" boarding pass through their smartphone app, if this is the case for your airline and airport - then you don't even need to reprint anything at all.

Comment: I had the option for a mobile pass during web checking, but can find it now.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what airlines you're referring to....but visiting a manned check-in desk is definitely the preferred option for MOST passengers. (Note: ryanair is an exception - all other airlines will allow you to seek help from a customer service representative).

Flight bookings these days can be complicated, and it's always best to seek assistance from the airline staff. Self-service compliments the whole check-in process, but should never be a complete substitute for dealing with airline staff.

Answer (score -5):

If you opted for a web check-in when you did your ticket purchasing, then you MUST come to the airport with a printed boarding pass of the web check-in. I am talking about coming with the actual paper print. I've just flew from Sofia to Tel Aviv yesterday and I had to pay a 35 Euros fee.

Comment: As the other answers above say this very much depends on the airline you're flying, their rules and where you're flying to and from. I do this all the time with no problem so saying you MUST is very misleading.