# I did an online checkin with Etihad with no access to a printer - how can I get my boarding pass now?

Tags: tickets, online-resources, paperwork, etihad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do when you can't print your boarding pass?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9035/what-to-do-when-you-cant-print-your-boarding-pass)

I just went ahead and did the online checkin for my flight tomorrow with Etihad because I thought it might improve my chances of getting an aisle seat as I prefer.

But I wasn't thinking about boarding passes for some reason! Then I got a couple of screens in and was told that online boarding was complete and there were buttons to print out my boarding pass... but I'm on a netbook connected to a shopping mall free Wi-Fi and have no printer access. (Maybe I should've printed to a PDF but I didn't think of that fast enough.)

So I tried using my "Ethiad Airways record locator" code number to go back in. I found my flight details but I didn't find options to print out my boarding pass again.

Is there a way to print it out again from their website? Can I still get it at the airport even though I'm already checked in? Would they charge me for such a thing? What should I do?

Comment: My question is potentially Etihad-specific if there's a possibility of an answer telling me how to get back in and print out my boarding pass from their website, but if not then yes it does look like a dupe otherwise.

Comment: @HaLaBi: I was in the process of trying that answer when my netbook battery quit and the computer shut down so I can't verify it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you go to the airport, and obtain your boarding passes there.

There are three ways you'll get them at the airport:

1. If they have check-in machines, you can walk up to them and simply print the boarding pass (note: depending on how crappy the software is, you may not be able to print them - this hasn't happened to me in years, though, since the machines improved).
2. You can walk up to the baggage drop-off and ask them to print the boarding pass for you. Depending on how busy/annoying they are, they may send you to a machine, though.
3. You go to the normal check-in counter. This is guaranteed to work out fine, but may take a while, depending on how many other people are queuing.

Whatever solution you choose, remember that as soon as you get to the "print your boarding pass" stage, you're checked into the flight. Thus, you're on the flight according to their system (which is good if they kick people off an overbooked flight due to check-in order), which means it'll be quite a hassle for them if you didn't make it to the gate. So you're all fine.

Comment: This worked fine. The guy at the desk said "I see you've already checked in." and I said "Yes but I didn't have a printer to print my boarding pass". And he responded "Well that's why I'm here". (-:

Comment: @hippietrail: Great! Glad to be of service.