# What should I do after buying an airline ticket?

Tags: air-travel, tickets

After I buy a ticket online for an airline, should I go to the airport and register it or is it enough to go to the airport at the date of flight and not to do anything?
How can I pass the gates to get myself to the waiting room for the flight? Do I have to print the ticket for this purpose? I have not bought an airline ticket online, so how it works is not known to me. The flight is an international flight.

Comment: @BrianCoolidge This is actually an excellent question. How can you know how it goes, if this is going to be your first flight?

Comment: GREAT question, yashar.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It covers enough that I feel much more confident about my flight in a couple weeks.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It would depend on the airline and the airport/country but no matter how you buy the ticket, the next big step is what's called “checking in”. This is when the airline assigns you a seat and confirms that you will indeed be flying.

In most cases, you can now check in online a few days to a few hours before departure and print the boarding pass at home (or wherever you can find a printer). You can then show up at the airport and present this self-printed boarding pass together with your passport to drop your luggage off and go through the security and police check (where applicable). Some airlines/airports also allow you to use a smartphone app as your boarding pass.

Alternatively, it's also possible to check in at the airport itself, possibly for a fee. I have not done that in quite some time (preferring online check-in), but, back when I did it regularly, giving my name and presenting an ID was typically enough for the staff to find my booking. If using some automatic check-in machine, scanning the passport or presenting the credit card used for the booking was sometimes necessary.

In any case, you do need to be at the airport in advance (depending on the circumstances up to 2 or 3 hours before departure are recommended) but not to go there in the days before.

Finally, note that your ticket should include some confirmation number that you could write down to help the airline find your booking should any problem arise.

Comment: Bringing the passport is the most essential part, just emphasizing that :)

Comment: @Bernhard Or so other form of identification depending on whether your flight is domestic or international or EU based...

Comment: @AdityaSomani Are you 100% sure? A drivers' license is considered as identification. However, it does not list citizenship, so a valid drivers' license does not proof that I am allowed to stay in the country.

Comment: @Bernhard It depends on the airline and country rules. The idea is simply that one form of identification depending on what is required. Not necessarily passport.

Comment: Quite often, it is also possible to check in and drop off luggage a day in advance at the airport. If you have an early morning flight, or have to leave the hotel in the morning but have an evening flight that could be convenient.

Comment: All good points (including the edit about the boarding pass on smart phones) but I tried to keep things simple.

Comment: If the journey is domestic, then you won't be passing through immigration controls, so you don't need a passport.  International journeys within the Schengen area (many countries in Europe, especially western and central Europe) are treated as domestic for this purpose.  But you always need ID to fly, so that the airline has an accurate record of who is on-board the plane.

Comment: @RichardGasden In fact, it's [possible to fly without ID at all in the Schengen area](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35015/does-any-airline-in-the-world-allow-air-travel-without-government-identification) and in some cases a national ID card is also enough to fly out of the Schengen area (e.g. to the UK or to holiday destinations around the Mediterranean) so the distinction isn't as sharp as it seems. But again, I tried to keep the answer as simple as possible and focus on the general case.

Comment: @Bernhard My french friends at least fly with their national ID (not the passport) in the schengen zone. That said I've no idea how you'd fly without ID at all in the Schengen area - I always needed my passport (Austrian).

Comment: @Bernard: US/Canadian Driver's license is sufficient for travel inside the US. Also, it's convenient to be able to fly with national ID within Schengen if you happen to forget your passport at home :)

Comment: ... and don't forget to bring a pen.

Comment: @Jonas Sure, but national ID is a replacement for a passport (slightly cheaper in my country). I really don't believe that you can travel by plane between Schengen countries with only your drivers' license.

Comment: Richard, some airlines in the UK may require a passport on domestic flights - I'm thinking Ryanair specifically, although they may have since relaxed the rule to include driver's licence.

Comment: Often enough, within the EU and after online check-in, I have not been asked for any type of ID at all.

Comment: Caution: some airlines now _require_ online check-in and passport registration in advance. I got caught out by this a few years ago when I hadn't flown for a while, and ended up paying a hefty "admin fee" at the check-in desk for just showing up with my ticket like in the good old days.

Answer (score 28):

Just to repeat Relaxed's excellent answer.  Yash, the process is:

(1) **PURCHASE** a ticket. These days, that is almost always online at say Expedia, or over the phone.  You'll get some sort of purchase code, like XFD123HHC

[image]

Note that these days, it's usually confusing since there is both an EXPEDIA code **AND** a code from the AIRLINE!  (Possibly even more than one airline.)  So, write all those down, or if you prefer print it out from your computer.

(2) **CHECK-IN.** At the airport, you "check-in". This means you **give them** your code numbers, and you **show them** your passport, and you **give them** your luggage. In return they **give you** your boarding pass.

Note, as it says you give them your luggage. But any small "carry-on" items, you just keep in your hand.

So, "check-in" is all about **getting your boarding pass**.

Boarding passes almost always look like this:

[image]

(3) Next, AFTER checking in, you **go through security**. You have to **show them** your **boarding pass** and also your passport again.  They scan you and your small "carry on" items. You then enter the departure area of the airport.  **Only** people who are actually flying, can go there - you have to say goodbye to your family as you enter the security check point.

Now - you go shopping! :) There are always shops in the departure area. In any large airport, it is like a shopping mall. Once again, the only people in the departure area are people who are actually flying - they have a boarding pass in their hand.  (And of course people like police, shop-keepers etc who have special passes to be in the "passengers only" area.)

(4) Finally you **board** the airplane. This happens at the **gate**. You have to give them your boarding pass and show them your passport. At the gate they remove and keep the large part of the boarding pass (on the left in the image above) and you keep the small part (on the right). The only reason you keep the small part is to remember your seat number. (if you happen to drop it or lose it it is no big deal.

So after shopping, you all stand around at the gate. Eventually they will say "Now boarding, your flight 247". You all line up and go through the gate - as I explain, they take your boarding pass, you show your passport, and they give you the small tear-off piece. At that instant you do and must walk straight on to the plane (down the walkway) and that's you on the plane. (You cannot go back to the shops, or anywhere else, after that.)

To recap:

(1) **purchase** online. Give: credit card number, Get: reservation number(s).

(2) at the airport: **check-in**.  Give: reservation number(s) + luggage.  Show: passport.  Get: boarding pass.

(3) at **security**.  Show: boarding pass + passport.  Get scanned (you and your carry-on bags).

You're now in the "departure area" which is often like a mall. Passengers only.

Wait until you hear "Flight 247 now boarding at gate 44B..."

(4) at the **gate**.  Show: boarding pass + passport. Walk on to the plane and sit down, you cannot return to the departure shopping now.

Notes:

(A) traditionally, you only got your **seat assignment** at the moment of checkin. ie on the actual day, at the airport. However these days...on the web, after you buy the ticket, typically you can click and actually choose your seat, so that's good. (In fact, nowadays, most airlines now have a con where you can then pay a little more for a "better" seat.)

(B) at most big airports, in fact, you can "check-in" - so, leave your luggage with them - right on the road where you get out of the taxi. Sometimes you do that and you ALSO have to then check-in at the main check-in counters inside; sometimes all the check-in is handled at the roadside.

(B2) To add more confusion, these days you can often check in using a machine that looks like an ATM.  Instead of having to line up to talk to a human at the check-in counters, you line up to use a little sort of machine; they might have a row of ten or so of these machines.  You just type in your numbers and it prints out the boarding pass for you (see image above).  Note that in this case you have to put your bags "somewhere", sometimes a person comes and gets it, sometimes you use the roadside system, sometimes you then go to another counter etc. Personally if it was my first time I'd just **go to a human at a check-in counter!** I would not use the "automatic machine" nor the "roadside check-in".

(B3 !!) *And note that these days, you sometimes do not need to check-in at all! If you have only hand baggage, in some cases you can "check in online." You do that at home even before going to the airport. I would avoid this if you are new!*

(C) note that check-in is the part where you "have to wait" - those are the long lines you see at airports. it can often happen you have to wait for an hour in the line.  some people like to arrive very early, to be the first to check in, so you don't have to wait.  note that by doing that you can get a better seat (BUT that does not apply so much these days, as explained above: you can usually choose your seat in advance, online.)

the wait to go through security CAN BE very long, particularly say in the US. the wait to actually board is no big deal, you all just line up and go on the plane.

I hope it helps you, or some other readers! more and more people are flying for the first time, so, enjoy.

Comment: Quite a few airlines in Europe expect everyone to check in online and print their own boarding pass, so only the baggage drop-off is done at the airport.  For the cheaper airlines, you may get charged a significant fee for the airport check-in, if you have't done it online; for example, Ryanair charges 70 EUR/GBP (about a hundred dollars) for that - possibly more than the ticket itself.

Comment: that's a good point actually.  things are changin'.  perhaps the OP should tell us **where they are flying from**

Comment: @Peteris, How does that work for people who are traveling and don't have access to a printer?

Comment: @ThePhoton http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9035/what-to-do-when-you-cant-print-your-boarding-pass

Comment: @ThePhoton the question linked by Jan Fabry goes into detail, but in short - you print somewhere (hotels/hostels do that), use a self-checkin machine if available, or get the pass on your mobile phone.

Comment: @JoeBlow. Thank you for photos. As I added the flight is international. I think it would be better to address the question without regard to my destination to make it as general as possible. The point made by Peteris is indeed good to know.

Comment: It's also probably worth noting that the boarding process really isn't as simple as "everybody lines up and gets on the plane" - most airlines will offer boarding first for first-class passengers, those traveling with small children, or those who may require additional time to board. (Wheelchair-bound, etc.) After that, they still will usually board in smaller groups so the entire load of passengers isn't rushing the gate. Some assign groups back-to-front, some according to when you checked in, and so on. If you try to board before your group is called, you'll be sent back.

Comment: "Boarding passes are always the same size all around the world, they look like this".  No, they aren't.  I have encountered boarding passes in the following variety in addition to the one you showed: letter or A4 self-printed passes.  Boarding passes displayed only on iPhones or other devices.  Plastic laminated cards that are collected and re-used for subsequent passengers (low cost airlines).

Comment: Joe - they can charge you money to print the pass at the airport, or they can deny you boarding. It's quite simple.

Comment: @JoeBlow The sad thing is that the airlines that insist on the passenger printing the boarding pass at home happen to be the ones who are only reachable using "premium" phone numbers. So the call can very easily be more expensive than just copying the PDF onto a USB pen drive and having it printed out at the next copy shop.

Comment: At least one airline (Air Canada) now extends the seat-assignment "con" to requiring you to pay extra to select any seat at all in advance (not just "premium" seats.)  If you don't want to pay, then it's just like it was in the old days:  you get your seat assignment at check-in.

Comment: yeah that's pretty common in europe too, Michael.  it's the new normal!  emirates, lufthansa .. many airlines now work like that.  a common system seems to be, perhaps 24 hrs before hand you can select your seat for free; any time before that you have to pay to choose a seat. note that this is **particularly onerous for families**.  it's basically insane you have to pay to get 5 or 6 seats together.  otherwise some innocent passengers are stuck sitting next to kids. it's really nuts.

Comment: very good answer - it might be worthwhile to mention the limitations on what can be carried in the hand luggage, albeit this of course varies a bit by jurisdiction. The "liquids" limitations are probably most unexpected for a new traveller - the "no sharps" one is a bit easier to understand, but it is still quite easy to miss those nail scissors in your manicure bag.

Answer (score 8):

It definitely needs to be noted that some airlines these days require the flyer to [present the original credit card](https://www.flymango.com/en/manage-travel/at-the-airport/check-in-and-security) used to book the ticket upon check-in too. This is an attempt to reduce internet fraud. Check with your airline if this is the case, as the airlines are generally super strict if they follow this policy (no credit card, no flight, no exceptions!)

Comment: I read the linked article. Never heard this before, and after 30+ years of flying, have never been asked. Many of my flights were business trips, and I don't even know what card the tickets were purchased on. Driver's license, and passport, if overseas, has always been enough.

Comment: Being a web developer who works quite a lot ecommerce sites, I highly doubt airlines can force customers to show the credit card. The site should be PCI complaint to store the credit card numbers (legally) which costs a lot of money. If the passenger name/PP number matches the details in the PP, you should be fine. They can probably verify with the last 4 digits and first 4 digits (tells what type of card it is) in extreme cases.

Comment: I don't know how that could be practical- especially if you purchase the ticket weeks or months in advance, your chances of having the same credit card number active are significantly less than 100%- what with all the fraud activity. There must be a 'plan B' available.

Comment: This is in South Africa. The main carrier here is South African Airways (SAA). They have a low cost subsidiary called "Mango" (the South African equivalent of RyanAir/EasyJet etc). I believe both SAA and Mango have this "present credit card" requirement. If you lost the credit card you need a police certified affidavit. Or if someone else is booking the ticket for you, I believe you need a photocopy of their ID, a photocopy of the credit card and a signed letter from them.

Comment: @mccdyl001 impossible to enforce for all the reasons mentioned. If you fly for business, you don't have the card, if it was even paid for by a card. Same with charters, and any other flight you get as part of a packet deal. And if you're booking through an agent, the agent's name is on record as the one paying (and you'd be paying the agent, possibly using a bank transfer rather than a credit card).

Comment: I agree wholly, but it doesn't change the fact that they do [check for credit cards](https://www.flymango.com/upload/Forms/Mango%20Terms%20and%20Conditions%20of%20Carriage.pdf) - section 6.4. OP didn't mention the countries he's flying to/from, so I mentioned this as it could make his life easier if going via one of the aforementioned carriers in Southern Africa.

Comment: We've had this problem for business trips where the passenger was not the cardholder. Emirates.

Answer (score 2):

When you buy a ticket online (or otherwise) you get a reservation code.  Normally one could print out a confirmation email just so you have that code on paper for reference.  With that code on the date of the flight you will go to the airport to the counter of the airline that sold you a ticket and a lot of airlines nowadays provide electronic means of checking-in for the flights so once you check in and check your bags in if any you will get your boarding passes printed  and with them go through security to the gates and then onto the plane.

There are other methods that are allowed for check-in such as online check-in which is open 24 hours before the flight in most cases, which will let you print the boarding passes and take them with you and go straight to security unless you have to check your bags and so on.

Comment: I don't think it's helpful to talk about "registration" when every airline I've ever come across calls this process "check-in".

Comment: While I have not actually used the confirmation e-mail for anything in many years I always print it just in case.

Comment: And don't forget that you often are required to submit other data before you can check in. Think passport and visa details.

Answer (score 2):

If flying to South Africa or even simply transiting through South Africa and you are taking minors (anybody under the age of 18) with you, there were some [recent regulations](http://www.flysaa.com/za/en/flyingSAA/News/New-regulations-for-children-travelling-to-and-from-South-Africa.html) passed in the country which will be very relevant to you:

All minors have to travel with full unabridged birth certificates (i.e. showing both parents). Both the named parents have to be travelling together with the minor. If only 1 parent is travelling with the minor, an affidavit authorising the travel from the other parent is required along with a copy of their passport/ID. If a minor is travelling with neither parent then affidavits from both parents are required and the copies of their passports/IDs. The only way out of the "affidavit from other parent" requirement is if the travelling parent has single-custody of the minor in question (and can show the paperwork) OR if the travelling parent has the death certificate of the other parent. If any of these documents are not in English, a sworn translation into English needs to be supplied too.

This is a rather ill-thought-out policy to try stop child trafficking and child traffickers using South Africa as a hub. Unfortunately it has been passed into law so there will not be much you can do if you are lacking in documents. If you are flying into or through South Africa your airline should have warned you by now already and check your documents at check-in. These laws kick in on the 1st October 2014.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add one factor missing from other answers.

After you buy ticket from a travel agent, you should always immediately double-check **following 4 things** by either calling up the airline office OR by visiting `manage my booking` section on airline website.

1. Validity of the ticket (i.e. does the PNR number - last name combination exists in airline database)
2. Baggage allowance for individual flights in your journey (related [Airline and Travel Agent disagree on baggage allowance, who do I need to resolve it with?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39256/airline-and-travel-agent-disagree-on-baggage-allowance-who-do-i-need-to-resolve)
   )
3. [In case of connecting flights] will the baggage be through checked-in till the final destination? Some airlines may not have agreements with others for baggage transfer.
4. [In case of connecting flights] Will you get all the boarding passes when you check-in for originating flight or will you need to get BP for connecting flight at a transit transfer counter?

Answer (score 0):

The process in summary:

1. Buy the ticket online or from a travel agent. You will get a proof of purchase (either as paper receipt or an attachment to your email). You need to bring this with you to the airport.
2. Once you arrive at the airport, you need to obtain a boarding pass in order to pass security and board the aircraft.

   To obtain the boarding pass, you have to present yourself, proof of reservation and some form of identification to the airline.  If you have luggage that is too big (or contains items not allowed in the cabin) you can give this to the airline to be checked in and carried in the cargo area of the aircraft.

   Typically you walk to the check in desk (these usually open 2 hours before the actual flight time; although at some larger airports major airlines offer checkin up to 24 hours before the flight departure) and hand your receipt from step 1, along with your passport to the agent. They will check your eligibility to fly, ask you some basic security questions, and give you one or more boarding pass(es) depending on the nature of your journey.

   These days, thanks to automation many airlines are offering self-service check-in kiosks. You approach a kiosk and scan your passport, which recognizes your name and then prints the boarding pass.

   Some airlines allow you to check in from their mobile applications directly, even bypassing any kiosks.

   In these situation if you self check-in, you can also walk upto specially marked stations and deposit any luggage that you want to check-in (that is, not carry with you in the cabin).
3. Once you have obtained the boarding pass - you and any luggage you wish to carry to the aircraft must pass security checks before you can enter the secure area of the airport, from where you will board your aircraft.

   Security requirements vary greatly between airports, however the most common requirements are:

   a. Remove your laptop / tablet from your bag and present it separately for scanning. Sometimes, they may ask you to turn on the laptop.

   b. Remove your coat, belt and (sometimes your shoes) and place them on a tray for scanning separately.

   c. Any liquid/gels should be presented in a clear plastic bags for separate inspection. Normally, any liquids you are carrying (such as water bottles) are not allowed and the personnel will ask you either finish your drink or discard it.

   Depending on the airport you may walk through a metal detector, a particle detector (looks like a booth and you stand in it with your arms raised), be subject to a manual search, or all of the above. The security process can be a bit stressful if this is your first flight.
4. Once you have passed security, you may be required to clear immigration. You should walk up to the officer and present your passport and your boarding pass. At some airports (such as the US) there are no exit formalities at all and for some flights (such as those within the Schengen zone) may not require any passport controls.
5. Once past security and immigration you are in the transit area of the airport. You can relax and do some shopping or grab a bite to eat before your flight. Be mindful of your boarding time and plan to be at the gate before this time.
6. Once you arrive at the gate, your boarding pass will be scanned and you may be asked to show your passport as well. From here, you simply board your plane and your flight starts.
7. Once you arrive at your destination, simply follow the signs for "Baggage Claim" or "Immigration / Customs".
8. As you are on an international flight, you may first be required to go through immigration. Simply present your passport to the immigration officer; they may ask some questions or request some additional documentation from you (such as a copy of your hotel reservation where you will be staying). Be polite and answer their questions.
9. After immigration, you are ready to collect your luggage - which will arrive on a series of moving belts. You may also be subject to a customs check; where they inspect your luggage and ask you questions about what you are carrying.
10. Once past customs - congratulations - welcome to the new country!